# How do I invoke a JavaScript function from an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript

I implemented a JavaScript routine to display articles between specific dates. It seems awkward, and I should be able to invoke the JavaScript function directly from the tag. I call the JavaScript program to load the function definition in the Head section, then I do this now:

```
<article id="myarticle">
<p>text of article</p>
<script>displayBetween("myarticle","05/19/2023","06/01/2023")</script>
</article>
```

I want to do something like:

```
<article id="myarticle" onload="displayBetween('myarticle','05/19/2023','06/01/2023')">
<p>text of article</p>
</article>
```

... or even better, without the id ... but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Fred

Comment: What exactly does `displayBetween()` do? Can you post the function definition?

Comment: The `load` event only occurs for elements that load their contents from an external resource, like `<script>` and `<img>`. Why do you think you need to invoke the function from the tag? Just run it from the `<script>`.

Comment: displayBetween is a function which turns the CSS value "display" to "none" if the current dates is outside the bounds of the second or third argument. So I code an "<article>" in advance of a date I want it displayed for example, and/or I want to make sure it no longer appears after a certain date (the third argument). The first argument simply relates the function back to the correct <article> via its "id" value. I was just trying to find a way to invoke the function directly from <article> rather than have to specify the call to the <script> each time. So I guess this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Some things about this really don't make sense to me. For example, won't `displayBetween("myarticle","05/19/2023","06/01/2023")` always display the same content? If so, then why have JavaScript at all rather than the static content?

Another issue: from the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article), `<article>` only supports global attributes, and `onload` is not among them. My suggestion would be to add `onLoad()` to `<body>` (although `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { })` is a better approach), and perform document.getElementById('myarticle').innerHTML = {some contet}.